# Executing update query, with prepared statement

Tags: java, mysql, sql

```
 int selectie = toernooienUitvoer.getSelectedRow();
        int selectiec = toernooienUitvoer.getSelectedColumn();
        String primarykey =  (String) toernooienUitvoer.getValueAt(selectie, 0).toString();
        String waarde = toernooienUitvoer.getValueAt(selectie, selectiec).toString();

        String columnaam = toernooienUitvoer.getModel().getColumnName(selectiec).toString();
        String input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("wijzig geselecteerde data", waarde);
        toernooienUitvoer.setValueAt(input, selectie, selectiec);   


PreparedStatement stat = con.prepareStatement("UPDATE fullhouse.toernooi SET ? = ? WHERE toernooi.T_code = ?");
        stat.setString(1, columnaam);
        stat.setString(2, input);
        stat.setString(3, primarykey);
```

Guys, i know the query is correct, if i input the values. my guess my mistake is somewhere in the preparedstatement
i am getting a MySQLSyntaxErrorException:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in other answer, the placeholder `?` can only be used for values, not for table and column names. Since you are not reusing the `PreparedStatement` this is quite simple.

Change from

```
PreparedStatement stat = con.prepareStatement("UPDATE fullhouse.toernooi SET ? = ? WHERE toernooi.T_code = ?")
```

to

```
PreparedStatement stat = con.prepareStatement("UPDATE fullhouse.toernooi SET " + columnName + " = ? WHERE toernooi.T_code = ?")
```

And adjust the index parameter in the `setString` calls.

Comment: but that isnt safe for mysql injection? someone has mentioned that on here

Comment: If you are accepting column name as input, you need to verify it using other mechanism, you already seem to be doing something converting from `selectiec ` to `columnName`, if the column name is invalid then you don't need to execute the statement at all

Comment: just validate the variable if it comes from input (check it's one word, identifier and so on)

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you can use place holder for dynamically passing the column name,your query should be:

```
"UPDATE fullhouse.toernooi SET colname = ? WHERE toernooi.T_code = ?"
```

Comment: but that column name changes, i need for it to be based on a selection?!?!? i also thought that might of been the problem

Comment: @hamchi In that case you better use a variable, but I dont think this is good idea.

Comment: @smit, yes can't :) I can't edit the comment anymore so I am going to delete it

Answer (score 0):

When you use bind variables, it means the statement is precompiled and on the next executions, it will be faster. You are trying to make the name of the column to be a bind variable, which is not possible.

because you obviously need to update several different columns, in order to achieve some speed, you should declare several prepared statements, one for each column. Keep them in a `HashMap<String, PreparedStatement>`

Answer (score 0):

The column name of a prepared statement cannot be dynamic because, depending on the column name, the query plan will be wildly different (e.g. sometimes table scan will be the fastest, sometimes using an index, sometimes something even more esoteric).

If SQL can't rely on a certain plan being the fastest, it needs to come up with a new one every time - which means there's no point in making a prepared statement which is why you can't do it.